# DNN Multiple views with one module - container skin not persisting

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN module that has multiple views. The issue i am running into is the container skin does not persist throughout each view.

For example, I have my page whatever.aspx setup with contains my module, the page is set to the the skin/container i want, and the module container is set to the container I want. When I navigate to one of the other views using NavigateUrl() the container does not persist, the site default container is used, instead of the container I want to use for module.

I can't find anywhere to set the container for specific "tabids" within the DNN reference so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the "ctl=VIEWNAME" method of changing views, you are seeing the "edit" container being displayed. You have a couple of options here for this.

1) Use a specific edit skin, that defines which container is loaded for a specific pane (where the module is)
2) Change your module to go with a different approach that letting DNN load the views. I have an example of this in my DNNSimpleArticle module, check out the View.ascx file, and the View.ascx.cs file http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/View.ascx

I personally prefer #2

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but I can play with this. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Hi Chris Hammond. I don't know why DNN only allow one edit skin? I don't see any advantage in your sample. It make me hard coding a lot instead configure on runtime. With MS SharePoint, i can create a user control and show up it any where without create too many module definitions. Can i do that with DNN?